# How to hide the button when click at a time it will show the current time and date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a submit button that will show **current date and time** when clicked and then the button will be hidden I mean button will be replaced by **time and date**. I saw an example but it showing GMT and current location name. So how can I replace button and show the time?

Using this code is showing the **date and time with GMT and location name** but it's not remaining and the **page is reloading** and the just appear the button only. I don't need to show location name and GMT I just need to show **current time and date**.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("#button-to-hide").hide();
        $("p1").show();
    });

});
$('#button-to-hide').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<form method="post" action="{{route('signInUpdate','id')}}">
  {{ csrf_field()}}
  <input type="hidden" name="isSignIn" value="{{$internalVisitor->isSignIn}}"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="tableId" value="{{$internalVisitor->id}}"/>
  <button type="submit">
<a id="hide" onclick="document.getElementById('hide').innerHTML = Date()">Hide</a></button>
</form>
```

Comment: can you add a plunker or a stackblitz for this?

Comment: no sir. @ Anuradha Gunasekara

Comment: Can I do it only using a single button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `toLocaleDateString()` to take the short date. Then you can take hours, minutes and seconds separately. Try the following way:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var d = new Date();
      var t = d.getHours() +':'+ d.getMinutes() +':'+ d.getSeconds();
      $("#p1").text(d.toLocaleDateString()  +'  '+ t);
      $(this).parent().hide();
      $("#p1").show();
    });
});
$('#button-to-hide').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="isSignIn" value=""/>
  <input type="hidden" name="tableId" value=""/>
  <button type="submit">
  <a id="hide">Hide</a></button>
  <p id="p1"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: One problem. Actually, I just want to make a record for sign in and sign out time. In this code it showing the time and date successfully but when I reload my page then the button come again. I don't want back the button I just need the date and time after clicking the button, date time will be always remaining . So what will the better way? Although I store the current time in DB should I show that time replacing the button? or is there any other way? Please help !!

Comment: And one more thing that I have los of visitor so, the button will be every visitor in the table.

Comment: @Md.AbuZaman, when the page load first what is the value in the database? If it is null or empty then show the button otherwise hide the button and show the value in the `p` tag....

Comment: the value in date time in db. but my button is in the table. so when I add new visitor the button is not working.

Comment: now I am trying to hide the button forever if click and success. I just take a span and store db value and hide that span initially then when click the button will relace by the span value. But I have facing a problem for each buttton. Please help me.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hideDate").hide();
 $("#hide").click(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 $(this).parent().hide();
 $(".hideDate").show();
 });
 });
 $('#button-to-hide').hide();
</script>

Comment: <td>
 <form method="post" action="{{route('signInUpdate','id')}}">
  {{ csrf_field()}}
  <input type="hidden" name="isSignIn" value="{{$internalVisitor->isSignIn}}"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="tableId" value="{{$internalVisitor->id}}"/>
  <button type="submit">
  <a  id="hide">Sign In</a></button>
  <p id="p1"></p>
 </form>
 <span class="hideDate">{{ $internalVisitor->signInTime}}</span>
</td>

Answer (score 2):

Since it is inside a form you need to prevent the default behavior of the button using `e.preventDefault`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hide").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('hide').innerHTML = Date();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="">

  <button type="submit">
    <a id="hide">Hide</a></button>
</form>
```

Comment: It's working fine normally. But it's not working with my form. And I don't want to show GMT +6 and Bangladesh Standard Time